# Having an issue with the switch operator

Tags: javascript

In this action I am trying to say...
if `VS_WRNG` is Blank and if `VS_WRNG` is `DSC` or `DSQ` then set the two items
but when I click on VS_WRNG in my web app and select DSC it didn't autofill the `BOB_TYPE` answer with LIN.

Did I screw up the code or is it the ! not working like that and do I need to do a `switch (true)` & case `(VS_WRNG != "")?`

```js
//Set BoB Type [TEMPORARY]
    switch (!VS_WRNG) {
        case "":
            switch (VS_WRNG) {
                case "DSC":
                case "DSQ":
                    switch (VS_BTYP) {
                        case "":
                            setValue('BOB_TYPE',"LIN");
                            VS_BTYP = "LIN";
                        break;
                    }
                break;
            }
        break;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `!VS_WRNG` always returns a boolean, so it will never be `""`.

Comment: Use `case false:`

Comment: Why are you using `switch` in the first place? Just write `if (VS_WRNG)`

Comment: Don't nest a `switch` for the same value. `VS_WRNG` is never going to be simultaneously `""` *and* `"DSC"`.

Comment: But why do you even need to test this first? Just use the cases for the values you care about.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's not simultaneous -- the first switch is inverting it.

Comment: @Barmar Inverting a string?

Comment: switch isn’t an operator.

Comment: @HereticMonkey He was expecting non-null to invert to `""`, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems very "risky" and a really bad habit that triple level switches...As explained on top of my comment: 
```!var``` will always return ```false``` so you'll need to use ```case false:``` instead of ```case "":```

Edit : Typed enter without shift so the comment was post.

You'll just have to test ```if(VS_WRNG)``` implicitly checking if it is true cause ```Boolean("")``` is equal to false

Comment: @Barmar I'm using the switch statement because I read somewhere that switches are faster than if's and I am trying to optimize loading time as this is a rather large program so I am trying to take every avenue to optimize code efficiency and speed.

Comment: It might be faster than a bunch of `else if` for many different cases. But not for a single case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue you're having is that `!VS_WRNG` always results in a boolean. It can never result in an empty string `""`. So the `case "":` will never run. But even if it did, your code still won't work:

> In this action I am trying to say... if VS_WRNG is Blank and if VS_WRNG is DSC or DSQ then set the two items

VS_WRNG cannot be simultaneously Blank and DSC or DSQ. You need to rethink your logic - the requirements are incompatible right now and quite illogical.

---

This is also quite an abuse of switch statements. If your switch statement has one case, it's an if statement. Just use an if statement like this:

```
if(VS_WRNG === "") { ... }
```

Your middle switch statement can be implemented also with an if statement, since you've written it to just check for two conditions:

```
if(VS_WRNG == "DSC" || VS_WRNG == "DSQ") { ... }
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the Switch statement because upon doing some research I learned that they are faster than If's, that is why i chose to do nested switches.

Comment: @TonyCodesDaily Switch statements have some interesting optimizations involving relative jumps to binary lookup tables hard coded in the resulting machine code. This only applies when there are many case statements. For a small number of cases, I suspect they may actually be slower, due to introducing overhead when all that's needed is a simple branch.

Comment: @TonyCodesDaily Further, even if they are faster it's by one or two instructions and this scale of microoptimization will only destroy your ability to work efficiently and maintain your code.